# Are there any additional robo center downloads for the nxt-g software?

Tags: instructions, nxt-g

It would be nice if there were additional entries under the animals, vehicles, machines and humanoid tabs. Supposedly there was some official LEGO web component to the software which appears to be gone with the introduction of the EV3. IS there somewhere to find content from that site?

Comment: Are you asking what happened to the NXT software robot plans? The ones that were animals, humans, machines, or vehicles?  One my pc, there is one animal, a scorpion.  It is located at file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/LEGO%20Software/LEGO%20MINDSTORMS%20NXT/engine/EditorVIs/Academy%20Content/activities/animals/scorpion/01/slide-inst.html

Comment: Yes. That sort of thing. I figured there would be more available. However I haven't been able to find any.